# Compute $\frac{\partial \ln|A+B|}{\partial a_{ij}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

before diving into the question, i admit that i don't know anything about matrix calculus, but i need it for my master thesis.
Given two symmetric matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, i need to compute $\frac{\partial \ln|A+B|}{\partial a_{ij}}$. From the [matrix notebook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) i know that $\frac{\partial \ln|A|}{\partial A} = A^{-T}$. Then, i've done this derivation:
$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial \ln|A+B|}{\partial a_{ij}} = \frac{\partial \ln|A+B|}{\partial (A+B)} \frac{\partial(A+B)}{\partial a_{ij}} = (A+B)^{-T}\frac{\partial A}{\partial a_{ij}} = (A+B)^{-T}J_{ij}
\end{align}
$
where $J_{ij}$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with only a 1 in position $(i,j)$ and 0 elsewhere.
Is it somehow corret?

Comment: $|A| = \det(A)$ ? From, Equation (49) of the matrix notebook: $\frac{\partial \,\det(A)}{\partial A} = \det(A)\,A^{-T}$ .

Comment: @DanielCunha, yeah sorry! I stupidly forgot a $\ln$ in front of $|A+B|$, which is indeed the determinant

Comment: Is B a constant matrix?

Comment: @DanielCunha $B$ does not depend on $a_{ij}$

Comment: Then you are right, below I present the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Einstein Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Let's define: $f(\mathbf{A}) = f^*(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}) = \ln(|\det(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})|)$

From Equation (57) of the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf):

$$ \frac{\partial\,f^*(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})}{\partial\,(A+B)_{pq}} = (A+B)_{pq}^{-T}$$

---

Since $\mathbf{B}$ does not depend on $\mathbf{A}$, we have:

$$\frac{\partial\,(A+B)_{pq}}{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial A_{pq}}{\partial A_{ij}} = \delta_{pi}\,\delta_{jq} $$

where $\delta$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

---

Therefore:

$$ \frac{\partial\,f(\mathbf{A})}{\partial A_{ij}} = \frac{\partial f^*(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})}{\partial\,(A+B)_{pq}} \,\cdot\, \frac{\partial\,(A+B)_{pq}}{\partial A_{ij}} = (A+B)_{pq}^{-T}\,\delta_{pi}\,\delta_{jq} = (A+B)_{ij}^{-T}$$

In matrix notation:

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial\,f(\mathbf{A})}{\partial \mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{(A+B)^{-T}}}$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the existence of the Einstein notation. Check me if i'm wrong: from my solution i can obtain yours rearraging all the terms knowing that $(A+B)^{-T}J_{ij}$ depends only on the $(i,j)$ entry?

Comment: Actually, in your notation, the result should be $(A+B)^{-T} : J_{ij}$ (where ":" denotes the inner product). But there is no need to use such a $J_{ij}$ matrix, since you will have to compute $(A+B)^{-T}$ anyways.

If you are interested in specific terms of the result, I would suggest you to access them through $\mathbf{e_i}^T \,(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-T}\,\mathbf{e_j}$, where $\mathbf{e_i}$ is the vector with $1$ in the $i$-th position and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: The last thing: can you explain me why the result should be the inner product between $(A+B)^{-T}$ and $J_{ij}$?

Comment: As you wrote it, both $(A+B)^{-T}$ and $J_{ij}$ are matrices, their matricial product will result in another matrix. However, as you wrote it, this should be the derivative of the scalar $f(A)$ with respect to the scalar $a_{ij}$, which must be a scalar value. So, there is an error. When using the chain-rule to derivate functions with respect to matrices, the "product" must be an inner-product. I won't be able to explain much more than this in the comments...

Comment: In Einstei notation: $\mathbf{A} : \mathbf{B} = A_{ij} \, B_{ij}$

Comment: In fact, i've seen in the matrix cookbook (137) that this involves the trace function...but why? But for now i stick with the kronecker delta, which i've better understood. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114027/discussion-between-daniel-cunha-and-federico-belotti).

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}$For
typing convenience, define the matrix variable
$$X = A+B = X^T \quad\implies\quad dX=dA$$
and the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2 \\
}$$
Write the function using the above notation, then use [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Alternative_Derivation) to calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log\det X \\
d\phi &= X^{-T}:dX = (A+B)^{-T}:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A} &= (A+B)^{-T} \\
}$$